# Python: extract text from docx to txt via parsing word/document.xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, docx

I would like to extract text from docx files into simple txt file.
I know this problem might seem to be easy or trivial (I hope it will be) but I've looked over dozens of forum topics, spent hours trying to solve by myself and found no solution...

I have borrowed the following code from [Etienne's blog](http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/).

It works perfectly if I need the content with no formatting. But...
Since my documents contain simple tables, I need them to keep their format with simply using tabulators.
So instead of this:

> ```
> Name
> Age
> Wage
> John
> 30
> 2000
> ```

This should appear:

> ```
> Name      Age     Wage
> John      30      2000
> ```

In order not to slide into each other I prefer double tabs for longer lines.
I have examined XML structure a little bit and found out that new rows in tables are indicated by tr, and columns by tc.
So I've tried to modify this a thousand ways but with no success...
Though it's not really working, I copy my idea of approaching the solution:

```
from lxml.html.defs import form_tags

try:
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import XML
except ImportError:
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
import zipfile

WORD_NAMESPACE='{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
PARA = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'
ROW = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tr'
COL = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tc'


def get_docx_text(path):
document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)    
xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
document.close()    
tree = XML(xml_content)    
paragraphs = []    

for item in tree.iter(ROW or COL or PARA):    
    texts = []
    print(item)    
    if item is ROW:    
        texts.append('\n')    
    elif item is COL:    
        texts.append('\t\t')    
    elif item is PARA:    
        for node in item.iter(TEXT):    
            if node.text:    
                texts.append(node.text)    
    if texts:    
        paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))    
return '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)

text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(get_docx_text('input.docx'))
text_file.close()
```

I'm not very sure about how the syntactics should look like. The output gives nothing, and for a few trial it resulted something but it was even worse than nothing.

I put `print(item)` just for checking. But instead of every ROW, COL and PARA items it will list me ROWs only. So it seems like in the condition of the for loop the program seems to ingore the or connection of terms. If it cannot find ROW, it won't execute the 2 remaining options but skip instantly to the next item. I tried it with giving a list of the terms, as well.

Inside it the if/elif blocks I think e.g. `if item is ROW` should examine whether 'item' and 'ROW' are identical (and they actually are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `X or Y or Z` evaluates to the first of three values, which is casted to `True`. Non-empty strings are always `True`. So, `for item in tree.iter(ROW or COL or PARA)` evaluates to `for item in tree.iter(ROW)` — this is why you are getting only row elements inside your loop.
2. `iter()` method of `ElementTree` object can only accept one tag name, so you should perhaps just iterate over the whole tree (won't be a problem if document is not big).
3. `is` is not going to work here. It is an identity operator and only returns `True` if objects compared are identical (i. e. variables compared refer to the **same** Python object). In your `if... elif...` you're comparing a constant str (ROW, COL, PARA) and `Element` object, which is created anew in each iteration, so, obviously, these two are not the same object and each comparison will return `False`.
4. Instead you should use something like `if item.tag == ROW`.

All of the above taken into account, you should rewrite your loop section like this:

```
for item in tree.iter():    
    texts = []
    print(item)    
    if item.tag == ROW:    
        texts.append('\n')    
    elif item.tag == COL:    
        texts.append('\t\t')    
    elif item.tag == PARA:    
        for node in item.iter(TEXT):    
            if node.text:    
                texts.append(node.text)    
    if texts:    
        paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))
```

Comment: The first point you mention is so trivial that I cannot believe I have not thought about it...
Well, about half an hour before your answer I had found some code from which I figured out the rest.
Afterall, I think you have solved my question.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above won't work like you asked. This should work for documents containing only tables; some additional parsing with `findall` should help you isolate non-table data and make this work for a document with tables and other text:

```
TABLE = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tbl'  

for item in tree.iter():   # use this for loop instead
    #print(item.tag)
    if item.tag == TABLE:
        for row in item.iter(ROW):
            texts.append('\n')
            for col in row.iter(COL):
                texts.append('\t')
                for ent in col.iter(TEXT):
                    if ent.text:
                        texts.append(ent.text)
return ''.join(texts)
```